# Minecraft chunk file decompresssion

Tags: minecraft-modding, file-format, compression

First of all, hello everyone,

I'm currently making a program to read Minecraft region files (r.#.#.mca) for a server.
The problem I have is that I can't decompress them, I tried GZip and ZLib decompression but none of them worked. I already searched for solutions but there is little to no information online. It's *really* important that I find a solution to that issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [The docs say Zlib is what's used](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Region_file_format#Chunk_Data), so it sounds like you're on the right track. Can you give more details of what exactly you've tried (step by step) and in what particular way these approaches failed to work?

Comment: Well, I first used the jnbt library as it provides methods to read NBT files but it expects gzipped files. When I tried to read region files it crashed and told me that the files weren't in GZip format. So, I then tried to use the Inflater class from the Java zip API because it uses the zlib algorithm. But this time it tells me "unknown compression method". That's where I am right now.

Comment: If I'm reading the docs correctly, it sounds like each block of "chunk" data in the file is Zlib compressed individually, not the .mca file as a whole. So you're going to need to start by parsing the chunk information tables to slice out each block of the file you want to decompress. Have you done that yet?

Comment: Well, I didn't see that bit, I'm gonna try and see what I can do.

Comment: So, I tried my best but still not working. Out of all the files I've tested, none seemed to follow the format from the wiki page (MCRegion format). They say it has not changed since, but it seems it did anyway. I didn't find any information about the precise structure of .mca files.

Comment: I finally found out! I found the `AnvilChunkLoader` class and copied the lines from the `loadChunk__Async` method and it worked. Thanks for the help nonetheless ;)

Comment: Minetest is an open source voxel game. One of the users wrote a python tool to convert minecraft maps to the minetest map format and released that tool under an X11-ish license. The relevant forum thread is https://forum.minetest.net/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=13709 Maybe this can help with understanding the minecraft file format.

Comment: Now that I found the appropriate functions, I don't need to bother with it anymore. But thanks for the link anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the `AnvilChunkLoader` class, copied its `loadChunk__Async` method and it worked.
This class can be found at `net.minecraft.world.chunk.storage.AnvilChunkLoader` for Minecraft 1.8.9
You have to find the method `loadChunk__Async(World worldIn, int x, int z)`.
The part I needed was:

```java
DataInputStream datainputstream = RegionFileCache.getChunkInputStream(chunkSaveLocation, x, z);
if (datainputstream == null) {
  return null;
}
NBTTagCompound tag = CompressedStreamTools.read(datainputstream);
```

To make it work, you need to specify the path to the region folder that contains the file, then the chunk coordinates `x` and `z`. The `tag` variable should contain the chunk data in NBT format.

Comment: This answer would be even better if you described where to find this class, or included a summary of the code you ended up using and how to work with it. The more information you share, the easier you make things for the next person to run into this problem the way you did. Try to write the documentation you wish you had when you started. ;)

Comment: I can't before 2 days it says :/